# Is there a tool for front end developers to see changes on the browser LIVE while coding css?

Tags: css, browser, sass, less

Usually when I code **css/scss/less** and make a change, I need to refresh the browser to see the latest changes, I have a dual monitor setup and I think it would be very handy to configure the **browser** or a specific **tool/IDE** to see the changes live on the browser, without having to refresh the page.

Comment: For small changes in css you can always use developer tools. Just press F12 on your browser.

Answer (score 2):

Gulp example

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less');
    browsersync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('less', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/*.less')
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
  });

gulp.task('bs', function() {
  browsersync({
      proxy: 'localhost:9000'
  });
}); 

gulp.task('default', ['less','bs'], function(){
  gulp.watch('./src/*.less', ['less']);
  gulp.watch('./dest/*', browsersync.reload);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sublime as your text editor you can use [livereload](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LiveReload)

there are some tools will do the job for you like 
[CodeKit](https://incident57.com/codekit/index.html) for mac 
[Prepros](https://prepros.io/) for windows

Im using prepros on windows and its very cool

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Easy Auto Refresh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc) if you have Chrome.
You can also setup Grunt/Gulp to watch your changes and livesync your browser.

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me like [@Rahul's list of tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40147743/1241736) is going to include what you're looking for, but [@JustinRvt mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40147569/1241736) that you can use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)… I currently use Gulp in my typical workflow, so here's the most basic example of how that would work.

To understand really what's going on here, and to get Gulp installed on your computer, you'll need read a Gulp guide (I recommend ["Gulp for Beginners"](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/); `gulp-less` documentation is [here](https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less), `gulp-sass` documentation [here](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass), and `Browsersync` documentation [here](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp)).

The way it works is you use `Browsersync` to run a your site on a local server, have `gulp` watch for changes to your stylesheet(s), and tell `Browsersync` to reload the page every time `gulp` detects a change in one of them.

This demo supports a folder structure like

```
project
  package.json
  gulpfile.js
  app
    index.html
    styles-less.less // any of these three < v vv
    styles-scss.scss
    styles-css.css
```

where `index.html` has

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-less.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-sass.css">
</head>
```

The `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    less = require('gulp-less'), // remove if you aren't using LESS
    sass = require('gulp-sass'), // remove if you aren't using Sass
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

// this gulpfile assumes
// - the simplest flat folder structure, where index.html and all stylesheets are in a directory "app" in the top level of the project directory
//      if the actual folder structure is different,
//          - adjust the  src, dest, and watch globs
//          - and use `browserSync.init({server: {baseDir: 'yourbasedirectory'}});`
// - that your html files `<link>`s one or more css files

// for every .less file, output a .css file with the original file's base name. Remove this task if you aren't using LESS
gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/**/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))
});

// for every .scss file, output a .css file with the original file's base name. Remove this task if you aren't using Sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('./app/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))
});

// initial compilation of the stylesheets, followed by initial set up Browsersync (which will handle the auto-reloading)
gulp.task('compile-and-serve', ['less', 'sass'], function() { // adjust (or remove) the prerequisite tasks if you're only using one (or neither) of LESS or Sass
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './app'
        }
    });
});

// this happens when you run `gulp`
gulp.task('default', ['compile-and-serve'], function() { // first compile LESS files, Sass files, and start Browsersync
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.less', ['less']); // if a change is made to a LESS file, recompile it. Remove this task if you aren't using LESS
    gulp.watch('./app/**/*.scss', ['sass']); // if a change is made to a Sass file, recompile it Remove this task if you aren't using Sass
    gulp.watch(['./app/**/*', '!./app/**/*.{less,scss}'], browserSync.reload); // adjust (or remove) the ! glob if you're only using one (or neither) of LESS or Sass
})
```

Comment: this runs a simple server to serve only static sites, is there an option to hoot browser sync with my own web server like apache.?

Comment: You'll need to change the Browersync configuration. This question should help [How do I get gulp + browsersync to work an apache ghost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191597/how-do-i-get-gulp-browsersync-to-work-an-apache-vhost), and see the [Browsersync `proxy` documentation](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-proxy)